# Share a thread between different activities

Tags: android

I'm about to develop an application for Android.

I need to continuously run an update thread that executes a task in a given interval. And this thread needs to be shared between activities.

I would also like to notify the active `Activity` when the thread executes a task.

In iOS I would execute a thread from the `AppDelegate` and then send notifications, but how do I achieve this with the Android SDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say create a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) that does the work for you. When it starts or finishes (or at any point you want), you can send a custom broadcast intent to indicate all parties that your service has passed this point. See [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).

If you want to start this `Service` periodically, also have a look at the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). That allows you send a broadcast intent periodically - in this case the intent that starts the service.

Also note that it's usually wiser to to terminate a service via `stopSelf()` when it's work is done. Run it again via intent when needed. Keeping it alive all the time isn't a good idea when it comes to battery life.

Answer (score 3):

Make a `service` and implement a `thread with infinite loop` and from there you can do your job....to update data in activity you can make a static method and you can call it from there with appropriate arguments....